# Select MAX value of Specific user on Datatable

Tags: c#, select, datatable

Im looking for a way to achieve the following:

I have a datatable:

```
ID    Custommer   Value  
1     Client 1     10  
2     Client 2     20   
3     Client 3     30  
1     Client 1     11  
2     Client 2     21  
3     Client 3     31
```

I need to select max value of Column "Value" of a specific id "id"

Ex.: Max value of client 1

should return: `1     Client 1     11`

But using this code:

```
dVipArchiveClientSelectd = dVipArchive
    .Select(id + "= 1" + " AND " + value + " = MAX(" + value + ")"); }
```

It fails to return. There's a way to achieve this using datatables and select ?

Comment: Is dvipArchive a DataTable instance?

Comment: You should add a groupby on custommer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IEnumerable with the group by on ID a Customer field, then apply the MAX to the Value field

```
var g = from t in dVipArchive.AsEnumerable()
    group t by new {id = t["ID"], cust=t["Customer"]}
    into grp
    select new 
    {
        grp.Key.id,
        grp.Key.cust,
        maxV = grp.Max(z => z["Value"])
    };
```

Now you have all the rows with the max value for each ID (and Customer)
Simply apply a WHERE to extract the row you are interested to

```
var row = g.Where (x => Convert.ToInt32(x.id) == 1).Single();
Console.WriteLine("ID=" + row.id.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Customer=" + row.cust);
Console.WriteLine("MaxValue=" + row.maxV);
```

I am NOT sure that this is better than executing directly an SQL Command like

```
SELECT ID, Customer, Max(VALUE) 
FROM Customers 
WHERE ID=@idParameter 
GROUP BY ID, Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(Value) FROM yourtable WHERE id=1 , dunno if was this what u wanted

UPDATE

```
string maxvalue = dt.AsEnumerable()

        .Max(row => row["Value"])
         .WHERE (//logic)

        .ToString();
```

Hope this can help u

Comment: you can't do that on C# DataTable